# Why is my GridView Rows.Count zero in my RowDeleting and RowUpdating Events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, count

I have a simple GridView binding to a table in my database. 
Everything looks good until I try to delete or update a row. 
I get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException because "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." 
After analyzing the output of my debugging I realized that my GridView had 0 rows in my rowDeleting and rowUpdating methods. This is the code in one of the methods:

```
protected void gvTermene_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.RowIndex); //result is 3, for example

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(gvTermene.Rows.Count.ToString()); //result is always 0
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)gvTermene.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        HiddenField hfID = (HiddenField)gvRow.FindControl("IDDoc");

        var connectionFromConfiguration = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MsSql Connection"];

        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionFromConfiguration.ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM TermenDocumente WHERE IDDocument={0}", hfID.Value);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                gvTermene.EditIndex = -1;
                bindDataToGridView();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                ltError.Text = exc.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConnection.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
```

What may the problem be?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you be looking for `DataSource.Deleting` instead of `GridView.RowDeleting`?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess here is that you are changing the view of the page when you enter this event called gvTermene_RowDeleting. Is this event doing a postback on your webpage. If it is, then you're probably losing the locally stored data that you pulled in from the initial SELECT statement you have placed somewhere else. I believe your best bet is to try to fit the statement that gives you gvTermene somewhere into your page_Load event.

You can get creative with this by calling other functions from the page Load that will have filters for your search criteria, etc.